# Why exec for avconv does not return the script video converting status?

Tags: php, exec, avconv

I'm using PHP `exec` command in order to convert videos by avconv linux library:

```
exec("avconv -i $mp4FilePath -acodec libvorbis -aq 5 -ac 2 -qmax 25 -threads 2 $webmFilePath > /dev/null &" , $output, $return);
echo PHP_EOL . 'Script output: ' . $return . PHP_EOL;
die;
```

Now When I run the php script the output is:

```
developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/domain/videos/avIBS0ZJmjCQBZV7eWqSWSe0u8lBgRCc.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-09-08 00:58:51
  Duration: 00:02:50.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 414 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 315 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-08 00:58:51
[libvpx @ 0x17bb220] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to '/var/www/html/domain/videos/avIBS0ZJmjCQBZV7eWqSWSe0u8lBgRCc.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-09-08 00:58:51
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libvpx, yuv420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1-25, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libvorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-09-08 00:58:51
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libvpx)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame= 4089 fps= 21 q=0.0 Lsize=    7151kB time=170.38 bitrate= 343.8kbits/s    
video:5288kB audio:1751kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead 1.538016
```

When Script has run and conversion is successful it waits at the last line nothing happens and `echo` command not executed, my script waiting for a signal to stop (I think so). When I press enter I will get back to shell.

Why return output is not printed out? How can I check whether video conversion was successful or not then?

---

**EDIT 1:**
When I removed `> /dev/null &`, I could see that script has ended successfully and `$return` has returned `0` for successful conversion (if I'm wrong correct me). But `$output` is an empty array. While I could see the whole output in shell that I've shown above. I want to log this whole data into log file.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your command directly? Maybe the call of avconv waits for some user interaction

Comment: @AlexanderBaltasar When I run it directly, script finishes successfully and shell is back to get command. And when I remove `> /dev/null &` shell is shown too and not waiting for enter, but the output is written to terminal instead of `$output` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I removed `> /dev/null &` in order to be able to get back to terminal after script work is finished. And then to get the avconv output inside of `$output` I appended `2>&1` to the end of the script.